# How to get milliseconds elapsed since midnight in R?

Tags: r

From the help of strptime and as.POSIXct, the  POSIXlt and POSIXct classes seem only to record whole seconds.

(I need the milliseconds to pass them as a seed to a random number generator in a shared object.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the printed times to sub-second accuracy by changing the options:

```
options("digits.secs"=6)
```

The maximum is 6 digits - see [options](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/options.html)

Then you can get the system time to millisecond accuracy using:

```
as.POSIXlt(Sys.time())
```

That will print the time. To get the milliseconds since midnight that you're after simply use:

```
mySeed = as.POSIXlt(Sys.time())
mySeed = 1000*(mySeed$hour*3600 + mySeed$min*60 + mySeed$sec)
```

Comment: Thanks.  I found this answer when I needed the intermediate midnight for other purposes: `myMidnight = mySeed -mySeed$hour*3600 - mySeed$min*60 - mySeed$sec` Then it is: `as.numeric(difftime(mySeed,myMidnight,'secs'))*1000`

Answer (score 1):

`?Sys.time` says:

> On almost all systems it will have sub-second accuracy, possibly
>   microseconds or better.  On Windows it increments in clock ticks
>   (usually 1/60 of a second) reported to millisecond accuracy.

So you can simply do this:

```
> foo <- Sys.time()
> foo
[1] "2014-05-22 12:40:55 CEST"
> hours <- as.POSIXlt(foo)$hour
> minutes <- as.POSIXlt(foo)$min
> seconds <- as.POSIXlt(foo)$sec
> hours*60*60*1000+minutes*60*1000+seconds*1000
[1] 45655771
```

In light of the help page, your results will depend on your system.

If you want to *print* the milliseconds, you can do this:

```
> options(digits.secs=3)
> foo
[1] "2014-05-22 12:40:55.771 CEST"
```